# Toggling NSWindow level for "always on top" behaviour

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, nswindow

I have a simple single-window application with a menu item that allows users to have the NSWindow appear always on top.

My function looks like this:

```
@IBAction func changeAlwaysOnTop(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (alwaysOnTopMenuItem.state == NSOnState) {
        alwaysOnTopMenuItem.state = NSOffState;
        window.level = kCGNormalWindowLevelKey;
    } else {
        alwaysOnTopMenuItem.state = NSOnState;
        window.level = kCGStatusWindowLevelKey;
    }
}
```

Turning "Always on Top" on works well - the window floats above all other applications as it should. However, when the option is turned off, the window continues to float above all other windows, as if `window.level = kCGNormalWindowLevelKey;` isn't actually doing anything.

I've tried different window levels, and I've tried ordering the window out and back in again. The window continues to float above all others.

How can I set the window back to normal after setting the level to `kCGNormalWindowLevelKey`?

Edit: the following Objective C code works just fine:

```
- (IBAction)changeOnTop:(id)sender {
    if (self.onTopMenuItem.state == NSOnState) {
        self.onTopMenuItem.state = NSOffState;
        self.window.level = NSNormalWindowLevel;
    } else {
        self.onTopMenuItem.state = NSOnState;
        self.window.level = NSStatusWindowLevel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting the menu state looks wrong; that should be done in your `validateMenuItem` method.  However I cannot see why the window level isn't changing; after reading the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/WindowLevel.html) it appears your code *should* work.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise it was a `swift` question initially.  Please tag your questions correctly so that I (and others) don't see it :)

Comment: Apologies - the swift tag says only to use it for swift language-specific questions. I think my issue is with the Cocoa API

Comment: Who knows with that <insert expletive here> language?

Comment: Hmm I could knock up a quick Obj-C app to see if that exhibits the same issues. This is my first foray into Swift.

Comment: @trojanfoe :D yes -- but in this case it is api based

Comment: Objective C code tested and working - @Ken Thomases provided the solution below. Looks like it is a Swift issue after all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using the wrong values for the level. You are using the keys by which window levels are looked up.

First, since you're using Cocoa, you should use the Cocoa constants for the window level: `NSNormalWindowLevel` and `NSStatusWindowLevel`.

If you look at the definitions of those constants, you'll find:

```
#define NSNormalWindowLevel kCGNormalWindowLevel
#define NSStatusWindowLevel kCGStatusWindowLevel
```

Notice the *lack* of the word "Key" on the end of those `kCG...` constants. If you then look up how those constants are defined, you'll find:

```
#define kCGNormalWindowLevel                        \
  CGWindowLevelForKey(kCGNormalWindowLevelKey)
#define kCGStatusWindowLevel                        \
  CGWindowLevelForKey(kCGStatusWindowLevelKey)
```

So, the values you used are keys that are passed to `CGWindowLevelForKey()` to get the actual level.

Comment: Thank you - this was the solution. I had to use `window.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(Int32(kCGNormalWindowLevelKey)));` (I mean, seriously, what the...???)

Comment: Thanks @colincameron for sharing the solution it helps me tons!

Comment: It's now `Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(CGWindowLevelKey.ModalPanelWindowLevelKey))` which still isn't much of an improvement. Why is there no `NSWindowLevel` enum?

Comment: And now it's `Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.modalPanelWindow))`!

Answer (score 5):

This works for me, and looks a bit nicer! (Swift 4)

```
    window.level = .floatingWindowLevel
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me in Swift 4.2.

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    view.window?.level = .floating
}
```